# Make Button in Android to repeat process inside activity until counter reaches certain number

Tags: android

I currently have Button in my main view which checks if users answer is correct.

```
Button CheckButton= (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.CheckButton);

    CheckButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
    public void onClick(View v) {
                // some action, setting text
        }
            });
```

If button is pressed once it checks if answer is correct, and if button is pressed second time I want it to repeat activity e.g. present user with another question.

OnClickListener is inside onCreate method and question is generated using switch and unique id (for game difficulty).

What would be the best way to set this repeat activity until it's been repeated 4 times. Thanks

```
switch (difficulty_level) 
{

case DIFFICULTY_HARD:

// do this

case DIFFICULTY_EASY:

// do this

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "repeat `Activity"`?

Comment: I think he means repeat the process that is inside of the activity, not restart the activity.

Comment: you are right process inside activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, this doesn't sound like logic belonging in the OnClickListener at all. The listener should simply register the click and then call a function in your activity "handleButtonClicked" that have access to fields that keep track of the number of clicks for the question, if the answer is correct and what the appropiate action is.

The fact that the OnClickListener is set in the onCreate only says that it is ready to be used after OnCreate. It doesn't require the OnCreate to be run again.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain correctly. Main activity is started when choosing difficulty level e.g. pressing button. 

Difficulty level is stored in global variable and corresponds to integer 0 to 4. OnCreate starts and shows main view and then goes to switch command which displays questions based on diff level. 

I want the question to be displayed again which doesn't necessarily mean that whole activity needs to start again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an anonymous inner implementation of OnClickListener, define it as a private class.

That way you can pass the parameter of how many iterations you want in its constructor / setter

Each time the application is launched, increase a counter; when such counter is bigger or equal than the said parameters, ignore the following clicks

Answer (score 0):

You need a global state variable that you set when the click has occured twice, or you could just count and every even number you change the question by loading another activity.

Comment: I have global variable int count=0;

And this can be accessed from within onClick listener. I just don't know how to define action.

when count reaches 2
display next question
which is located inside switch which displays questions based on difficulty.

Comment: On second thought it would be easier to use a boolean flag that you invert each time the user clicks the button.